# How to get access to Neo4j result when using UNWIND?

Tags: go, neo4j

I am learning Go as well as I am writing my first Go application that uses Neo4j. I will be UNWINDING slices of structs allot. The documentation is sparse at best, however, I was able to track down this Gist and I am running this **exact** code with the exception of my Neo4j credentials and the cypher query. https://gist.github.com/ali-ince/558d3c2a300d803ffc0bfdcbf166f3ff

I modified the Cypher query to return the entire User rather than just the ID.

`"UNWIND $list AS item CREATE (u:User) SET u = item RETURN u"`

If I modify line 82 to output the values:

`fmt.Println(result.Record().Values())`

I get:

`[0xc0000a6ea0]
[0xc0000a6fc0]
[0xc0000a70e0]
[0xc0000a7200]
[0xc0000a7320]
[0xc0000a7440]
[0xc0000a7560]`

Printing just `.Record()` gives me:

`&{[u] [0xc0000e07e0]}
&{[u] [0xc0000e0930]}
&{[u] [0xc0000e0a80]}
&{[u] [0xc0000e0bd0]}
&{[u] [0xc0000e0d20]}
&{[u] [0xc0000e0e70]}
&{[u] [0xc0000e0fc0]}`

I'm primarily looking to get the Neo4j Node ID for each node created. I know I can return just that but would like to know how to see all the properties. I do not know what to do with whatever the above is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`UNWIND` transforms the list into individual rows. If `$list` contains 10 items, then 10 users are created and returned. Each user via your driver, is a representation of a Node. And so your results will contain a list of `neo4j.Node` instances, from which you will be able to see the properties etc.